# Rails: heroku won't show youtube iframe in post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iframe, heroku, ckeditor

I'm using a `post` model that has a `body:text` as one of its fields. I'm also using ckeditor to allow users to style their posts. I've got youtube embeds working on the local server, but the iframe won't render in the heroku demo server.

In my view I have:

```
<p><%=  @post.en_body.html_safe %></p>
```

Which works on the local dev machine. I tried changing it to

```
<p><%=  raw @post.en_body %></p>
```

And that also works locally, but not in heroku.

If I view the page source in my rendered view, the iframe is indeed present:

```
<iframe frameborder=​"0" height=​"315" scrolling=​"no" src=​"http:​/​/​www.youtube.com/​watch?v=GWwsd5APlgw" width=​"420">​
```

But there's just nothing visible.

If I inspect the iframe, it is indeed not loading anything -> It loads a DOM with html and body tags, but there is nothing inside. All other html `<p>,<div>` etc, get's rendered fine. Everything loads as expect on my local machine

I'm loading other videos w/iframes elsewhere on the site, but those URLs are stored in the database and called like this:

```
<div class="video-container">
    <iframe width="100%" height="349" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<%= youtube_fix yt.link %>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Those ones work fine on heroku. I thought maybe it was a security-thing on heroku, but with the other videos loading fine, I'm stumped.

Also tried using different youtube urls, restarting heroku server and clearing my browser's cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use youtube's url as iframe's `src`. Use `embed` instead of `watch?v=`

This should be worked:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" height="315" scrolling="no" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/GWwsd5APlgw" width="420">​
```

And you have to notice, there are so many hidden characters of `â€‹` in your code:

[image]

It may happen if you are copying your code from msword or pdf. Type it manually or use a better editor like sublime text or vim.

Comment: Thank you so much! 6 years later, this actually helped me!